# Does not receiving message on Android Device in GCM

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project that include GCM as its main functionality.

I followed this [AndroidHive.com](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) for implementing GCM client and GCM server.

While running the html file in xampp server, I am getting this type of output on screen:

```
{"multicast_id":7075430686045407371,
  "success":1,
  "failure":0,
  "canonical_ids":0,
  "results":[
        {"message_id":"0:1394625413704378%93abcc37f9fd7ecd"}
  ]
}
```

Here I am not obtaining any type of message or notification on my Android device.

I don't have much knowledge about php, so I am not able to understand *what* is the matter.

Is there any problem with my php code or there is a problem in my Android code?

Comment: you added api key into config.xml file in PHP.

Comment: yes...i have replace key with mine

Comment: The response you got means Google accepted your message, so you don't have to worry about the server code. Can you post your client code and your manifest? Your problem is probably there. Do you get any errors in the LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have 3 things for your push notification to make it work.

Server side: **Project Id**(you can obtain from google cloud)

Client side: **API key**(from google cloud also) and **registration number**(your device ID)

Comment: ya i have obtain all the required things,but i am not able to obtain message on device

Answer (score 1):

First off, have you tried your PHP script just to see if a connection to Google servers was successful? Try echoing your response and see if all is well on that end.

Second, you need to build your `GCMBroadcastReceiver'java` client side to receive the messages:

```
package myApp.packageName;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.games.Notifications;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

/**
 * Handling of GCM messages.
 */
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context ctx;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        ctx = context;
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType))
        {
            sendNotification("MyNotificationTitle", "Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        }
        else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType))
        {
            sendNotification("MyNotificationTitle", "Deleted messages on server: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        }
        else
        {
            String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
            String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");



            sendNotification("Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        }

        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }

    // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
    private void sendNotification(String title, String msg) {

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                new Intent(ctx, myActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

In the `onRecieve()` method try printing a message to the log, any message, just to see if the event triggered properly.

Comment: i have obtaining this response from GCM server to my php script
{"multicast_id":8626675218964447268,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1394690855107399%b06e6126f9fd7ecd"}]}
what does this mean ?

Comment: It means you have succeeded in sending your message. Now you just have to work on receiving them client-side.